# proving fermats little theorem using group order

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\overline{a} \in \mathbb{Z}_p^\ast$ a group of order $p-1$ then we proved that $o(\overline{a})  | p-1$ so $p-1 = ro(\overline{a})$ then $\overline{a}^{p-1} = \overline{a}^{ro(\overline{a})} = \left (\overline{a}^{o(\overline{a})} \right )^r$

is there anyway I can conclude $\overline{a}^{o(\overline{a})} = \overline{1}$ to finish the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your question: yes. What is the identity in the **multiplicative** group $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$? And more generally, for an arbitrary group $G$, if $n$ is the order of $g\in G$, what is $g^n$?

Answer (score 1):

$a^{o(a)}=1$ by the definition of the order of an element.